# How to make css opacity property not to be inherited from parent div´s?

Tags: html, css

I want a black bar behind a png image, and i want the black bar behind the image to have opacity. When I apply opacity to the black bar, his child element (the png image) inherits this opacity. I dont want this to happen.

The site is www.tomasfleiderman.com.ar , where it says "work for money, design for love" I want a black bar behind with opacity.

The code is the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
font-size:40px;
color: white;
}
#caja
{

}
#fondofrase
{
}
</style>
<!--
<p>Work for money design for love</p>
  -->
<div  id="fondofrase">
<div  id="caja">
<div>
<img src="http://www.tomasfleiderman.com.ar/1.png" alt="Texto" height="60%" width="60%"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a semi transparent background color: http://jsfiddle.net/alessandro_pezzato/LWh75/

```
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, at least not easily.  Child elements have the same maximum opacity as the parent, so a child image can only have an opacity of, say, '0.6' if the parent has an opacity of '0.6'.  You could, though, use some absolute positioning techniques to layer the `div` and the `img` on top of each other as sibling elements rather than parent-child elements.

```
<style>
    #positioner {
        position: relative;
    }

    #theText,
    #theImage {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
<div id="positioner">
    <p id="theText">Work for money design for love</p>
    <img id="theImage" />
</div>
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting this style on the surrounding `<div>`-tag:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

However, the browser support of rgba is not perfect, and definitely something you should consider before going with this solution. It tends to break in IE versions below 9 (see link: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).